# Display query created with stmt

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code for inserting new row into the database:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO files_requests VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, {$userinfo['id']}, 0, ". time() .", 0)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('isssss', $listID, $files, $filesize, $audio, $subtitles, $fansub);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Is there a way to see the query after the bind_param is done?  I know I can use echo to view and see the variables: `echo "('isssss', $listID, $files, $filesize, $audio, $subtitles, $fansub)";` , I would like to view the query itself with the variables inside it. Is there any function I can run on the stmt object or mysqli, to display the query before it is executed, beside create an echo statement myself?

Comment: My guess is that MySQLI doesn't actually combine the string and params until right before it gets executed.